# Approximating a large number n using base b and exp e using python

Tags: python, radix, exponential, approximation, largenumber

So I have an arbitrarily very large number n, a random number consisting of 2000 digits; and I want to use exponents to approximate it as best I can without exceeding it. The answer has to be in the form of b**e and n is > 0. So far I tried base 2 but the gap between 2**e <~ n and n is still too big.

```
def highestPowerof2(n):

if (n < 1): 
    return 0

res = 1

for i in range(8*sys.getsizeof(n)):
    curr = 1 << i 

    if (curr > n): 
        break
    res = curr
return res
```

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: fixed all. i forget how accurate you have to be in here :P

Comment: You seem to be limiting yourself to integer e. Try not doing that. Use fractional steps after you exceed it using integers.

Comment: @ThomasWeller No, e is the exponent.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson ok makes sense, but I couldn't do 0.1 << i. I need the operation to be a bit fast too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226927/discussion-between-l-scott-johnson-and-justin-farrugia).